# .htaccess to redirect a specific page to root

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-302

There are several variant questions on this on SO, but I did not find one that answers my specific problem.

I want to add a rewrite rule to my htaccess that will take all traffic going to

```
http://example.com/blog/its-a-sunny-day
```

and redirect to

```
http://example.com
```

Ideally this should be done via 302, as it will be changed later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Redirect /blog/its-a-sunny-day http://example.com
```

This seems to work.

Comment: Note: this redirects to http://example.com/blog/its-a-sunny-day, not to the domain homepage

Answer (score 2):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^blog/its-a-sunny-day/?$ / [L,R,NC]
```

Answer (score -3):

Create a cgi/php file for sending a redirect header. Then write a rewrite rule to replace "blog/its-a-sunny-day" with "path/to/redirect.php". For example:

/redirect.php:

```
<?php header( 'Location: /' ) ; ?>
```

/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^blog/its-a-sunny-day$ /redirect.php
```

Comment: Why are we using php here when mod_rewrite can happily create a redirect too.