# htaccess redirect or rewrite with "?start=10 in URL

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect http://sitename.com/site-categories/78-sitename?start=10 to http://sitename.com.

Any direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried writing it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess to redirect a specific page to root](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063716/htaccess-to-redirect-a-specific-page-to-root)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your /htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /site-categories/78-sitename\?start=10 [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /? [NC,L,R]
```